# Writing image to Android's internal memory (OnePlus One)

Tags: android

The code below works perfectly to store image take from camera into external (sd card) mobile but for the mobile like OnePlus it fails  ...  I tried dozen of codes to write to internal memory but no succes .help.

```
PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Bitmap bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arg0, 0, arg0.length); 

        String pathofImg = saveToInternalSorage(bitmapPicture);

        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Path of img :"+pathofImg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI :",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Uri uriTarget = getContentResolver().insert(Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,new ContentValues() );

        OutputStream imageFileOS;
        try {


            imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriTarget);
            bitmapPicture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, imageFileOS);

            //bitmapPicture.    
            imageFileOS.write(arg0);
            imageFileOS.flush();
            imageFileOS.close();

            //get the full path  
            realpath =getRealPathFromURI(uriTarget);
            //Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"RealPath :"+realpath,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String filename=getFileNameFromPath(realpath);
            //Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"file name :"+filename,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            saveImageName(filename);
            //seperate the name and file path

        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        camera.startPreview();
    }};

    // not working ... :(
    private String saveToInternalSorage(Bitmap bitmapImage)
    {
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
         // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
        File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
        // Create imageDir
        File mypath=new File(directory,"profile.jpg");

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {           

            fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

       // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
            bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return directory.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

**Logcat**

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Writing to internal storage is not supported.

although the mode is MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE

Comment: Anything in the logcat?

Comment: Error in log cat was  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Writing to internal storage is not supported. although the mode is MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE

Comment: Log the actual path you are trying to write to.  Also, why are you changing the file mode? World writable is rarely a good idea.

Comment: Supposed to be `/data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir/profile.jpg`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the What i was missing was to use myDir.mkdirs();

here is the actual code the did the trick then i verified it from DDMS file explorer

```
    String afilpath =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir=new File(afilpath+"/E-Complain");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Toast.makeText(this, ""+afilpath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

But the strange thing in my oneplus i can see the folder using folder manager app but when i connect via USB to computer i cannot see the that file in computer .